# Выполнить функцию к переменной, а не к объекту

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть самописная функция `htmlcode();` возвращает преобразованный текст элемента.

Так работает:

```
alert($("#id").htmlcode()); //ok
```

Так нет:

```
var tmp = 'ok1';
alert(tmp.htmlcode()); //Uncaught TypeError: tmp.htmlcode is not a function
```

Как подправить?

Comment: Найдите одно отличие: `$("#id").htmlcode()` - `"ok1".htmlcode()`

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я нашел!

Comment: @PavelMayorov и всё же какой выход

Comment: @Grundy не создавать же какой-нибудь $("#id2"), давать ему значение и потом применять к нему функцию

Comment: @Rammsteinik а почему?

Comment: @Rammsteinik, а как ты думаешь, откуда берется функция _htmlcode_? Где она объявлена?

Comment: @Grundy это если быть точнее, метод

Comment: @Rammsteinik, метод чего? это раз. Это совершенно не мешает ей быть функцией, это два. Такой вызов (`tmp.htmlcode()`)возможен при добавлении этого метода в данном случае в прототип `String`, но это может быть бессмысленно. в зависимости от реализации функции

Comment: @Grundy суть в том, чтоб использовать var как селектор

Comment: `var` **нельзя** использовать как селектор, потому что это ключевое слово языка. Непонятно, в чем разница между _использованием var как селектора_ и использования селектора?

Comment: @Grundy по-моему, он хочет содержимое переменной использовать как селектор, если я его правильно понял.

Comment: @ilyapt верно поняли

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в следующем. Ваша функция htmlcode() объявлена как jQuery-метод. Соответственно она может применятся только к jQuery-объектам и ни к чему другому.

У вас она объявлена примерно так:

```
$.fn.htmlcode = function () {
    var text = $(this).html();
    // делаем что-то еще с текстом
    // и возвращаем его
    return text;
};
```

Это не очень гибкое решение. В вашем случае лучше всего вынести исполняемый код в отдельную функцию, таким образом вы сможете вызывать его как угодно. Вы можете даже расширить прототип объекта String. Примерно так:

```
function htmlcode (text) {
    return "!!!" + text + "!!!";
}

$.fn.htmlcode = function () {
    var text = $(this).html();

    return htmlcode(text);
};

String.prototype.htmlcode = function () {
    return htmlcode(this);
}

var result1 = $("#id").htmlcode();
var result2 = htmlcode("Еще какой-то текст");
var result3 = "Просто текст".htmlcode();

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
console.log(result3);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/okrb12zt/

Comment: _Соответственно она может применяться только к jQuery-объектам и ни к чему другому._ - почему же?

Comment: Приведите пример, jQuery метод удобно реюзается как-то еще?

Comment: можно сохранить метод в переменную и вызвать с чем угодно, некоторые проблемы могут возникнуть в зависимости от содержания метода, но это все равно не помешает вызвать его просто так, либо с другим объектом в качестве контекста

Comment: Подобный вызов не имеет практического смысла, особенно в ситуациях, когда содержимое метода жестко завязано на работу с jQuery-объектом, а не с чем-то еще. В такой ситуации гораздо правильней вынести какую-то общую логику в отдельную функцию.

Comment: имеет или не имеет смысл - это другой вопрос, применяться-то может.

Comment: Конечно, при желании все возможно. Но зачем запутывать автора вопроса? Понимание языка и его возможностей придет постепенно, а запутывать человека сразу сложными концепциями только отобьет всякую охоту изучать язык дальше.

Comment: Таки ты и запутываешь, говоря, что эту функцию больше нельзя ни к чему применить.